# Update batch error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I created a loop for my array and then next is the update batch but whenever i try to update 1 item my code doesn't update. I can't spot where's my error. How can I perform update batch in easy way?

Here's my code:

```
 /*THIS IS ALL ARRAY*/
 $id = $this->input->post('idx');
 $desc = $this->input->post('itemdesc');
 $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
 $price = $this->input->post('price');
 $status = $this->input->post('status');

 for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($id); $x++){

     $total[] = $price[$x] * $qty[$x];

     $updateArray[] = array(
        'poid' => $id[$x],
        'item_desc' => $desc[$x],
        'item_qty' => $qty[$x],
        'price' => $price[$x],
        'total' => $total[$x],
        'status' => $status[$x]
     );

     $this->db->update_batch('po_order_details',$updateArray, 'poid');  //I guess poid is my error but im not sure. I think my array won't find the correct id for where.

   }
```

Here's my array sample output:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [poid] => 5
            [item_desc] => Yakisoba
            [item_qty] => 15
            [price] => 40,000.00
            [total] => 600
            [status] => ACTIVE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [poid] => 6
            [item_desc] => Laptop
            [item_qty] => 5
            [price] => 15,000.00
            [total] => 75
            [status] => ACTIVE
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [poid] => 7
            [item_desc] => Speaker
            [item_qty] => 3
            [price] => 5,000.00
            [total] => 15
            [status] => ACTIVE
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [poid] => 8
            [item_desc] => Mouse
            [item_qty] => 5
            [price] => 500.00
            [total] => 2500
            [status] => ACTIVE
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [poid] => 9
            [item_desc] => Keyboard
            [item_qty] => 5
            [price] => 1,000.00
            [total] => 5
            [status] => ACTIVE
        )

)
```

That's all guys i hope you can help me.

Comment: What is the error ? which one is not updating ? set `DB_DEBUG` to  `TRUE`, also inspect the actual query.

Comment: also its looks like you are updating it inside the loop. You are creating an array through loop, so you need to execute the update after loop completed.

Comment: I can't update the data whenever i try to update.

Comment: Did you tried `last_query` ? copy the last query and try running manually.

Comment: i also tried to put outside my loop the $this->db->update_batch() but it is same effect.

Comment: Niloy posted an alternative answer, try to check that. Since you didn't posted the actual error, so everything is a guess. Sometimes it wont work even if syntactically everything is correct (sometimes your relations).

Comment: my error is for not updating my table. Thanks guys I found a solution for my question. But it is a long process. I create another array then i looped it with the array of my details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i did it, but my process is long

```
for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($id); $x++) {
    $total[] = $price[$x] * $qty[$x];
    $idvar = $desc[$x];

    $updateArray[] = array(
        'poid'  => $id[$x], 'item_desc' => $desc[$x], 'item_qty' => $qty[$x],
        'price' => $price[$x], 'total' => $total[$x], 'status' => $status[$x]
    );
}

for ($var = 0; $var < sizeof($updateArray); $var++) {
    $idx = $updateArray[$var]['poid'];

    $test = array(
        'item_desc'  => $updateArray[$var]['item_desc'],
        'item_qty'   => $updateArray[$var]['item_qty'],
        'item_price' => $updateArray[$var]['price'],
        'total'      => $updateArray[$var]['total'],
        'status'     => $updateArray[$var]['status']
    );

    $this->db->where('poid', $updateArray[$var]['poid']);
    $this->db->update('po_order_details', $test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing each of the value of the array in single quote and then execute the query. I have edited the code to enclose the array values into single quote. please try that.
Here is the edited code.

```
$updateArray[] = array(
        'poid' => "'".$id[$x]."'",
        'item_desc' => "'".$desc[$x]."'",
        'item_qty' => "'".$qty[$x]."'",
        'price' => "'".$price[$x]."'",
        'total' => "'".$total[$x]."'",
        'status' => "'".$status[$x]."'"
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this may be help you:

```
/*THIS IS ALL ARRAY*/
$id = $this->input->post('idx');
$desc = $this->input->post('itemdesc');
$qty = $this->input->post('qty');
$price = $this->input->post('price');
$status = $this->input->post('status');

for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($id); $x++){

 $total[] = $price[$x] * $qty[$x];

 $updateArray = array(
    //'poid' => $id[$x],
    'item_desc' => $desc[$x],
    'item_qty' => $qty[$x],
    'price' => $price[$x],
    'total' => $total[$x],
    'status' => $status[$x]
 );

 $this->db->where('poid', $id[$x])->update('po_order_details', $updateArray);
 //$this->db->update_batch('po_order_details',$updateArray, 'poid');  //I guess poid is my error but im not sure. I think my array won't find the correct id for where.

}
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I already solved it. But i will try your code. It seems that it is correct.